# How to identify the cause of an Active Directory lockout on client computer?

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

For several months I have been suffering Active Directory lockouts from my Windows 10 laptop, which I use in a networked, business environment. This happens around 4 times each day. Our IT administrator has checked the domain controller and assures me that the source of the lockout is my laptop.

In **Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System** I see this Warning at the time of the lockout:

[image]

'Computer' is indeed my laptop.

That is interesting but doesn't (I think) identify the actual program or service causing the bad logon attempt.  How could I identify that program/service?

Comment: `The shown error message is too late at this point the account was already locked. When where you last forced to change your account password? May be there is an program running on your system that have saved your credentials for remote access that now uses the old password. Backup programs are a common candidate...

Comment: [Netwrix Account Lockout Examiner](https://www.netwrix.com/account_lockout_examiner.html) is a good resolution to spotting the cause of account lockouts

Comment: Is the computer an AD member, or is it a standalone system with the SMB credentials manually saved?

Comment: It's an AD member

Comment: @Robert Your suggestion about a program with incorrect credentials is possibly correct, but how do I identify that program?

Comment: @Virtuality I would prefer not to use the Netwrix utility because of their license conditions.

Comment: @DavidA You can't identify the application on client-side (may be on server-side on the DC, but I don't have much experience on that), just go through the list of active apps and scheduled tasks and check or disable them one-by-one. Especially those apps are suspect that access network resources such as file shares.

Comment: A webpage I visit many times a day has a link to a page in a private folder. Even though I have not clicked on the link a logon dialog window pops up. It is a long shot but you might make note if you are using a browser when the lockout triggers.